# Android & CherryPy: Trying to upload a file, string, or bytearray from android app to CherryPy

Tags: android, http-post, cherrypy

I'm having trouble setting up the HTTP Post android app code to upload a file, string, or byte array to CherryPy. Can someone point me in the right direction?

I get HTTPError: (404, 'Missing parameters: myFile').
CherryPy code:

```
       html += """            <h2>Upload a file</h2>
        <form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        filename: <input type="file" name="myFile" /><br />
        <input type="submit" />
        </form></body></html>"""

def upload(self, myFile):
    out = """<html>
    <body>
        myFile length: %s<br />
        myFile filename: %s<br />
        myFile mime-type: %s
    </body>
    </html>"""

    size = 0
    f = open(myFile.filename, 'w')
    while True:
        data = myFile.file.read(8192)
        if not data:
            break
        size += len(data)
        f.write(data)

    return out % (size, myFile.filename, myFile.content_type)
upload.exposed = True
```

Android app code:

```
              String writeOut = "1,1234,4567,8910";
              byte[] byteArray = writeOut.getBytes();

              File tmpFile = new File("/sdcard/Download/tst.txt");

              HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams(); 
              params.setParameter("myFile", "myfile1");
              HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 15000); 
              HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 5 * 60 * 1000); 
              HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params); 
              HttpPost  post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.123:8080/upload"); 
              HttpEntity requestEntity = new FileEntity(tmpFile, "multipart/form-data;boundary=--");
              post.setEntity(requestEntity); 
              HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) client.execute(post); 
              int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
              HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
              String page = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
              Log.d(HTTPTAG, "reply: " + page);
              Log.d(HTTPTAG, "statuscode: " + statusCode);
```

Logs
CherryPy side:

```
192.168.1.114 - - [01/Aug/2012:10:10:25] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 404 1265 "" ""
```

Logcat side:

```
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966): reply: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966): "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966): <html>
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966): <head>
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;     charset=utf-8"></meta>
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):     <title>404 Not Found</title>
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):     <style type="text/css">
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):     #powered_by {
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):         margin-top: 20px;
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):         border-top: 2px solid black;
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):         font-style: italic;
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):     }
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966): 
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):     #traceback {
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):         color: red;
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):     </style>
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966): </head>
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):     <body>
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):         <h2>404 Not Found</h2>
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):         <p>Missing parameters: myFile</p>
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):         <pre id="traceback">Traceback (most recent call     last):
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):     response.body = self.handler()
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in __call__
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):     self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 40, in __call__
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):     raise sys.exc_info()[1]
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966): HTTPError: (404, 'Missing parameters: myFile')
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966): </pre>
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):     <div id="powered_by">
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):     <span>Powered by <a href="http://www.cherrypy.org">CherryPy 3.2.2</a></span>
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):     </div>
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966):     </body>
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966): </html>
D/MyApp.HTTP( 6966): statuscode: 404
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, 15000); 
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 5 * 60 * 1000); 

HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams(); 
params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.PROTOCOL_VERSION, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.123:8080/upload"); 

File tmpFile = new File("/sdcard/Download/tst.txt");
MultipartEntity mpEntity = new MultipartEntity();
mpEntity.addPart("myFile", new FileBody(tmpFile, "text/plain"));
post.setEntity(mpEntity); 

HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) client.execute(post); 
int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
String page = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
Log.d(HTTPTAG, "reply: " + page);
Log.d(HTTPTAG, "statuscode: " + statusCode);
```

Comment: Thanks, this along with the libraries at this link worked! http://blog.tacticalnuclearstrike.com/2010/01/using-multipartentity-in-android-applications/